# How to fix logging issues when setting state in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issue with state as i'm not 100% i'm using componentDidMount and componentWillMount correctly.

I have set the constructor and super props, and I am getting a user object with the getCurrentUser() method and setting the user state with the new object.

```
componentWillMount() {
  const current_user = getCurrentUser().then(user => {
    this.setState({
      user: user
    });
    console.log(user);
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state.user);
}
```

It logs the user correctly in componentWillMount, but logs an empty object in componentDidMount.

Any guidance would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Do you know that the promise has returned by the time `componentDidMount` is called? I'd put breakpoints in the `then` function and in `componentDidMount` and see which is being hit first

Comment: This is the exact reason why componentWillMount was deprecated. It has been misused like that most times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't use componentWillMount, 
Do it in componentDidMount.

In practice, componentDidMount is the best place to put calls to fetch data, for two reasons:

Using DidMount makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state properly, so you don’t end up with undefined state that causes errors.

If you ever need to render your app on the server (SSR/isomorphic/other buzzwords), componentWillMount will actually be called twice – once on the server, and again on the client – which is probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in componentDidMount will ensure that data is only fetched from the client.

Comment: Thanks for this, really appreciate the explanation! I'm actually using server rendering with Next.js and want to be able to pass the user state as props to use in other components as something like current_user={this.state.user}. If the componentDidMount needs to wait for the page to get rendered first, is this possible?

Comment: Yes.
You can do it like this inside the render method:
<div>{this.state.user && this.state.user!==undefined && <YourComponent current_user={this.state.user}/>}</div>
That makes sure the component is rendered only when the state is ready

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks so much for that! It was starting to melt my brain a bit

Answer (score 3):

`getCurrentUser` is an asynchronous method which calls another asynchronous method (`setState`).

I am pretty sure that you will first see the log entry from `componentDidMount` and only afterwards the log entry from `componentWillMount`.

What's happening is:

1. React calls `componentWillMount`
2. You start an async call (`getCurrentUser`)
3. `componentWillMount` returns immediatelly, without waiting for the promise to complete
4. React calls `componentDidMount`
5. Your promise resolves

Answer (score 1):

The logs are due to the `asynchronous` nature of your method `getCurrentUser`. When you call `getCurrentUser` in `componentWillMount`, it might result in an output after the `componentDidMount` has finished executing and hence you see the initial state in `componentDidMount`. However the console.log in `componentWillMount` is in the `getCurrentUser` `.then promise callback` which will log the current value received from `getCurrentUser()`